# .htaccess catch all subdomains & GET as GET variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

The following examples explain my problem.

This is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user.php?user=%1

RewriteRule ^user\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Expected:

```
http://example.com                      > /index.php
http://example.com/contact              > /index.php?path=contact
http://example.com/cat/sub1/sub2        > /index.php?path=cat/sub1/sub2
http://jack.example.com                 > /user.php?user=jack
http://jack.example.com/contact         > /user.php?user=jack&path=contact
http://jack.example.com/cat/sub1/sub2   > /user.php?user=jack&path=cat/sub1/sub2
```

Happened:

```
http://example.com                      > OK
http://example.com/contact              > It opens user.php?path=contact
http://example.com/cat/sub1/sub2        > It opens user.php?path=cat/sub1/sub2
http://jack.example.com                 > OK
http://jack.example.com/contact         > OK
http://jack.example.com/cat/sub1/sub2   > OK
```

I tried lots of way but didn't solve it. Any help?

Comment: BTW I think you confused index.php with user.php in your rules. Because in your .htaccess you have it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the same main domain, I would just include it in the rules instead of wildcards. Give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((?!www).+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /user.php?user=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((?!www).+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /user.php?user=%1&path=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^user\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: With these rules http://example.com/cat/sub1/sub2 works perfect but the subdomain one http://jack.example.com/cat/sub1/sub2 doesn't work. Path is coming empty.

Comment: Oh I _think_ I understand what you want. Try the updated rule now.

Comment: Previous one was better :) Now all links open index.php.

Comment: I forgot a flag on one of the rules. That should work just fine.  Try it again with update.

Comment: All links open index.php again. If there is a subdomain or subdomain+GET parameters in the URL, it must open user.php otherwise index.php. My above codes works but they're not exactly completed.

Comment: There is no way all links can open to index.php because when the subdomain matches in the first rule. It will stop at that rule. Also in order to have subdomain+GET you need another rule. You current rules don't account for that.  I updated the rules. `example.com` or `example.com+GET` should be the only thing that goes to index.php now.

Comment: Sorry it's my fault. Now `example.com` & `example.com+GET` works. Also `sub.example.com+GET` works. But `sub.example.com` open index.php.

Comment: That should work however, I made another little edit. Give that a try.

Comment: Nothing happen. This one is works for subdomain `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((?!www).+)\.example\.com [NC] RewriteRule .? user.php?user=%1 [L]`. But I can't combine with yours.

Comment: I've tested the rules and they work how you've asked. `http://sub.domain.com` should go to that first rule.

Comment: I got a temporary demo page. You can check http://sub.buisolur.com, http://sub.buisolur.com/cat/sub1/sub2. All of them works perfectly except `sub.example.com`. In the first address you're gonna see the file name. It opens index.php

Comment: Ok do you have the rules exactly how they are in my answer?

Comment: Yes. I just copy/paste & changed example.com to my URL. But as you can see the subdomain problem is continue.

Comment: I made a slight change to the rewriterule to the first subdomain rule. See if that helps.

Comment: Yes I just change the rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^$`

Comment: I tried it too before my previous answer. But nothing changes :(

Comment: Hmm, you can test the rules here. http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ Copy and paste everything starting from the first subdomain rule into the tester box. Then check all your urls. I think something else is the problem.

Comment: It always says "This rule was not met." on the line `RewriteRule ^$ /user.php?user=%1 [L]`. It means the code is not proper or something else? And when I delete `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` line it seems everythings great but in my host I give Internal Server Error.

Comment: What URL did you use with that rule. It shows me it's fine.

Comment: Remember I said when testing, the rules. Only copy the rules **after** `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`  Only test the rules starting with the subdomain rules.

Comment: Copied after `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` but now when I try `http://sub.example.com` it says the new url is `The new url is http://sub.example.com/index.php?path=`. It doesn't work properly.

Comment: That is impossible. I'm using the same test site. And I copied and pasted the rules above and when I use `http://sub.example.com` I get `The new url is http://sub.example.com/user.php?user=sub`

Comment: Yes you right. I had a mistake. Now when I give `http://sub.example.com` the output url is `http://sub.example.com/user.php?user=sub` but why when I put this code back `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` it doesn't properly?

Comment: I think I solved it. I just removed the line which `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]`. Looks working perfectly. Is there anything wrong with this removed line?

Comment: You mean in the tester? or your site? `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` won't work in the **tester** that's why I said copy everything below it which are your actual rules. The tester only supports some things. Read the bottom of the page.  But it will work on a live server.

Comment: The rules  with `REQUEST_FILENAME` just says that if it's a real file or a real directory do nothing. I assumed you didn't want to rewrite it if the request was a real file or directory.

Comment: You mean I can use your code except `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` line? Now everythings great in tester and also in my host.

Comment: You can use it without it, but something is weird with your host. You can remove those 3 lines after RewriteEngine. The main thing is that the rules work as I put them.

Comment: OK I understand. Maybe there is a problem in my host but I don't know. It seems everythings good now and I want to thank you so much. You really helped me.